# Detect periodic events within data

Tags: time-series

I have a collection of card transactions, each with a date, amount, card identifier and merchant. I want to determine if a card is making periodic payments to a given merchant. The issue is that the period is unknown, there may be some variance (i.e. different days in a month, sometimes the bill is paid a few days late), and there may be interspersed events that do not match the cycle.

Ultimately I want to extract the subset of transactions that are found to be periodic (if any exists)

I think to start with I would just use the date vs binary payments (i.e. whether a payment was made or not, disregarding amount)

Could someone point me to some approaches to this? My background is not in statistics and so far my googling has proved inadequate. Thanks

Comment: you should try spectral analysis to identify periods in your data above white noise, its background is not specially difficult. SAS has such a great implementation of it.

Comment: Why don't you post your data in an excel file , noting the start date and if applicable the country of origin and I will try and help you make sense of this.

Comment: Thank you for the offer, however due to the sensitive nature of the data I can't share it online (even anonymised). I liked your approach the most, but in the end I decided I don't need a perfect system and so knocked up a quick and dirty solution. I wrote an algorithm to extract the longest subsequence of transactions where the dates are all a common interval apart (+/- 10%). From there I used the average length of that subsequence / length of original sequence to determine which merchants were periodic billers. From there I was able to forecast by removing outliers not in the subsequence.

Comment: Sounds like you built a nice/creative work-around ....great job !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not recommend turning the data into 0/1 . I have had a lot of experience with daily  bank payment data , ATM access , deposits etc.. If the payments are systematic/regular to a particular day of the month then its is fairly straightforward to identify these patterns. If however the data is non-systematic then I would suggest a two stage approach. Stage 1 would identify pulses and record the date and the magnitude of the pulse. The second stage would require a rule-based approach where you took the pulses and the data es that were associated with them and pooled/analyzed them according to your specification i.e. things 1 day apart or 2 days apart from regular should be considered/classified as part of the same family. Another way is to use the size of the pulse/unusual value as the qualified for grouping. Detecting unusual activity requires a model that incorporates the routine e.g. day-of-the-week effects, holiday effects, weekly effects, monthly effects and any auto-correlative structure evidenced in your data. Commercially available software may have to  customized/improved to deal with this potentially thorny issue but that's typical of how software develops as a result of it's documented current inadequacy.

Comment: I'm curious about two issues: 1) how to detect _cyclical_ component instead of _seasonal_ (https://www.otexts.org/fpp/6/1); 2) how to actually **extract** subsets of data with cyclical behavior. I've looked at some R packages, but haven't seen any clear examples.

Comment: Detecting seasonal pulses is fairly easy using http://www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf . Detecting which  days-of-the-month are statistically significant/important is a unique feature of AUTOBOX http://www.autobox.com/cms/ which I have helped develop. If you wish to talk about this more perhaps you can contact me off line and I will try and help you.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply and nice links (though my current focus is the R ecosystem :). I will review the info and will do my best to understand it. In regard to talking, I very much appreciate your kind offer and will keep it in mind for the future. At the present time, I don't feel competent enough in time series (and in statistics, in general) to converse with experts. I'm currently busy preparing for my dissertation defense, so don't have a lot of time for stats self-education. I hope to be able to continue in the future, though. Again, your kind words are much appreciated.

Comment: If you have access to the monthly home sales series that was anlyzed vis-a-vis cyclical behavior in your reference  please send that to me as I will pursue it in advance of our next interaction.

Comment: I haven't read the FPP book in full, just browsed through some parts. However, the data set `hsales` from the linked example as well as other data sets from the book are available via `R` package `fpp`: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fpp. I hope that this is what you meant.

Comment: Strangely, I don't see `hsales` data set listed in `fpp` documentation. I also loaded the package and it seems that `hsales` is not there as well. Sorry - I should have checked that upfront. **UPDATE**: Found it in `fma` package: `data('hsales', package = 'fma')`.

Comment: can upload it via dropbox ? or send it directly to me at my contact info ...

Comment: Here is the text dump: https://gist.github.com/abnova/e51f7710304cb52eb821. For copy/paste, please use raw data: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/abnova/e51f7710304cb52eb821/raw/8c573c22aa780045ece970aa79fed70081668f1e/tsHSales.txt.